# Picasso Image in Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio, picasso

I have a simple question. How can I save Picasso image (that loads successfully from json) into database. I want to convert it into a bitmap if it possible, or is there another way to save it?
I tried this method for drawable images and its work perfectly.

My code:

```
public static byte[] imageViewToByte(ImageView image) {
    Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) image.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
    // Bitmap bitmap=(BitmapDrawable)image.getI);
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    byte[] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
    return byteArray;`.   
}
```

Comment: There is a callback listener for image loading in `Picasso`. When you'r image will download completely then you will get Bitmap object which will be your loaded image bitmap and save it to database.

Comment: Normally it is a bad practice to store the actual image in the Database except for its Uri. The image should remain as a file not a BLOB.

Comment: My image is loading from json then how can i save it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After successful load of image set to picasso then , use below  code to convert image url to bitmap :

```
 try {
    URL url = new URL("http://....");
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
} catch(IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

or, use below :

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
try {
    URL url = new URL(src);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.connect();
    InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
    Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
    return myBitmap;
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}
}
```

By using  [sharedpreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) ,you can save bitmap to internal storage .

Comment: i want to save it with the help of sqlliteopenhelper than how can i do this i pass the link of the image in the json the image is loading from json

Comment: @sajidamin, If you will save image then when you will retrieve image from Database without internet  , But if you will save url then again you have to use picasso with internet

Comment: simple i want to save the image in the favortie for favorite i make a database and in database i want to pass the byte array. as i mention above the method work successfully for the images that are avaliable in drawable but for picasso image that loaded from json its not working. i want to convert this picasso image into byte array and pass to the database

Comment: @sajidamin , Please tell me the problem , what you want to do ?

Comment: i have a json file with image url and other data...  i have a favorite button when user click on this favorite button the data is store in database successfully now every thing work fine but the image is loading from picasso and in database i want to save this picasso image how can i convert this picasso image into a bytearray to save it into a database.

Comment: That i already answered use top of my code to convert image to bitmap and  add to your database with other data  & when we want image to show convert bitmap to image .

Comment: or you can save directly images to database look into this https://acadgild.com/blog/save-retrieve-image-sqlite-android/

Comment: in up code instead of url want can i pass imageview in which the image is loaded from picasso

Comment: yes just pass the image url and save in string , no issue no need to convert into bitmap

Comment: the url is in the json file?

Comment: yes , just pass json image url , and again when you wanna set use picasso again